# setState not call in socket on method in second mount components

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, sockets

this is a code in the my Function Component in reactjs :
**  useEffect(() => {

```
    const callback = ({ conversationId, new_message }) => {

     console.log('new_message', new_message);

        setMessages((prev) => {

            console.log("into");

            return [...prev, new_message]

        });

    };



    socket.on('getMessage', callback);
}, []);**
```

In the first component mount ,it's work normal ,the method  setMessages working and re-render components but
when I unmounted components by using react-router-dom v6 and when I re-mount it, ,the method  setMessages not call ?

please help me

solve the proplem as soon as

Comment: im try this 
useEffect(() => {
  const callback = ({ conversationId, new_message }) => {
    console.log('new_message', new_message);
    setMessages((prev) => {
      console.log("into");
      return [...prev, new_message];
    });
  };

  socket.on('getMessage', callback);

  return () => {`enter code here`
    socket.off('getMessage', callback);
  };
}, []);

but when i mount component again socket.on not call